# D1 mini / esp8266 WifiManager

Tags: esp8266

So i have a D1 mini that I want to connect to the wifi.
I found the following code on the internet that is supposed to start a web server, that you can visit and then connect to the chosen wifi through the website. It will then remember the settings and try to connect to that wifi next time before it starts a web server - which is just what I need!
The problem is that when I connect to the wifi the d1 mini thinks it did just than - but when I visit my router and check it is not connected.

I cannot figure out why it thinks it's connected but is not, can anyone help me?

```
#include <FS.h>                   //this needs to be first, or it all crashes and burns...
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  //WiFiManager

  WiFiManager wifiManager;

  //reset settings - for testing
  wifiManager.resetSettings();

  IPAddress _ip = IPAddress(192, 168, 0, 35);
  IPAddress _gw = IPAddress(192, 168, 0, 1);
  IPAddress _sn = IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0);

  wifiManager.setSTAStaticIPConfig(_ip, _gw, _sn);
  if (!wifiManager.autoConnect("WemosAP", "ConfigureMe")) {
    Serial.println("failed to connect, we should reset as see if it connects");
    delay(3000);
    ESP.reset();
    delay(5000);
  }
  //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
  Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");
  Serial.println("local ip");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
void loop() {
}
```

btw: the ip 192.168.0.35 is free, and I have checked both the gateway and the subnet mask from my laptop by running ipconfig in cmd.

Comment: remove `resetSettings()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like the code is just broken. I found an example from the WifiManager library that is called "autoconnect". This just seems to do the exact same thing, just by also working:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          //https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino

//needed for library
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include "WiFiManager.h"          //https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager

void configModeCallback (WiFiManager *myWiFiManager) {
  Serial.println("Entered config mode");
  Serial.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
  //if you used auto generated SSID, print it
  Serial.println(myWiFiManager->getConfigPortalSSID());
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //WiFiManager
  //Local intialization. Once its business is done, there is no need to keep it around
  WiFiManager wifiManager;
  //reset settings - for testing
  //wifiManager.resetSettings();

  //set callback that gets called when connecting to previous WiFi fails, and enters Access Point mode
  wifiManager.setAPCallback(configModeCallback);

  //fetches ssid and pass and tries to connect
  //if it does not connect it starts an access point with the specified name
  //here  "AutoConnectAP"
  //and goes into a blocking loop awaiting configuration
  if(!wifiManager.autoConnect()) {
    Serial.println("failed to connect and hit timeout");
    //reset and try again, or maybe put it to deep sleep
    ESP.reset();
    delay(1000);
  } 

  //if you get here you have connected to the WiFi
  Serial.println("connected...yeey :)");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```